# Ubuntu 17.10 with Unity (workspace switcher)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I have installed 17.10 with Unity...
All works fine except the shortcuts I used to change between workspaces:

I had arranged a 2x2 grid
and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CursorDown</kbd> I could go to the bottom,
and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CursorUp</kbd> could go to the upper...
Now it is not working. Only with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>...
Any idea how to retrieve this functionality?
To the sides it works ok...

Comment: open ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) > Desktop wall > Bindings > Move within wall > & set keyboard bindings to Move Up & Move Down as desired.

Comment: You made my day friend!!!! It's working now... Thanks so much!!!!